# Why does [1].extend(my_list) return nothing

Tags: python

When I type `>>> [1].extend([2, 3])`

I expected Python to return `>>> [1, 2, 3]`

Why does it return `>>>` Ie. nothing

Comment: Because the method `list.extend` doesn't return a value. It changes the mutable-variable it is called on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list#extend()` doesn't return a value. It modifies the list **in-place**.
Here's an example:

```py
l = [1]
l.extend([2, 3])
print(l) # prints [1, 2, 3]

print([1].extend[2, 3]) # prints None
```

See [the Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) for more information.